# Redimensionar imagen en JLabel

Tags: java

Tengo este código, el cual crea una ventana y muestra un *JLabel* en el cual metí una imagen; la imagen es grande y solo me muestra un pedacito. Quiero saber como redimensionar la imagen para que se muestre en pequeño pero completa.

```
package pruebasgraficas;

/**
 *
 * @author -Super Mario Bross-
 */
import javax.swing.*;

public class PruebasGraficas extends JFrame{

private static JLabel et1;        
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        JFrame Ventana1 = new JFrame();

        Ventana1.setTitle("VENTANA 1");
        Ventana1.setSize(600, 600);
        Ventana1.setLocation(300, 100);
        Ventana1.setVisible(true);
        
        et1 = new JLabel();
        et1.setSize(300, 300);
        et1.setLocation(25,25);
        et1.setIcon(new ImageIcon ( "logo.jpg" ) ) ;     
             
        Ventana1.add(et1);
        Ventana1.setLayout(null);
        Ventana1.repaint();
        Ventana1.revalidate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

ImageIcon se crea por default con el tamaño que encuentra en el JLabel de manera que se ajusta a ella y no es posible visualizarla bien.
Puedes usar hacer un `getImage()` de la clase abstracta Image

```
Image img= new ImageIcon("logo.png").getImage();
ImageIcon img2=new ImageIcon(img.getScaledInstance(78, 124, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));

et1.setIcon(img2);
```